# Memoized in spek test give an error: "can not be accessed in this context"

Tags: kotlin, mockito, spek

When trying to make a spek test (new thing for us), we get an error while trying to verify the invocations on the mock. The error is:

> 'm3CustomerService' can not be accessed in this context.
>   java.lang.AssertionError: 'm3CustomerService' can not be accessed in this context.

I have not been able to figure out why this error keeps happening. Does anyone have any idea.

```
package com.crv.decustomeradapter.m3

import com.crv.decustomeradapter.m3.client.M3Client
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
import org.mockito.BDDMockito.then
import org.mockito.Mockito.mock
import org.spekframework.spek2.Spek
import org.spekframework.spek2.style.specification.describe

object M3CustomerServiceSpekTest : Spek({
    val m3ClientMock by memoized { mock(M3Client::class.java) }
    val m3LocationEligibilityCheckServiceMock by memoized { mock(M3LocationEligibilityCheckService::class.java) }
    val m3CustomerEligibilityCheckServiceMock by memoized { mock(M3CustomerEligibilityCheckService::class.java) }

    describe("Calling the mock") {
        it("makes it return empty list") {
            assertThat(m3ClientMock.unfilteredCustomersFromM3).isEmpty();
        }
    }

    describe("Initiating the service ") {
        val m3CustomerService by memoized {
            M3CustomerService(m3CustomerEligibilityCheckServiceMock, m3LocationEligibilityCheckServiceMock,
                    m3ClientMock)
        }
        describe("and calling it with no return values for the mocks") {
            val m3Customers = m3CustomerService.processM3CustomersFromM3()
            it("makes it return an empty list") {
                assertThat(m3Customers).isEmpty()
            }
            it("calls the m3ClientMock") {
                //This test gives the error
                then(m3ClientMock).should().unfilteredCustomersFromM3
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Update:
When using memoized to get the list the call to the m3CustomerService is never done, so the test fails.

Comment: You are using memoized wrong, have a look at https://www.spekframework.org/core-concepts/. tldr; You are getting this error because you are using a scoped value during the discovery phase (describe block is invoked during this phase) which is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

your `m3CustomerService` is declared as `by memoized`

which means Spek will create a new instance before each test.

so you can't use it as a normal `val` inside `describe(...)`

please move this line into `it("makes it return an empty list")`:

```
val m3Customers = m3CustomerService.processM3CustomersFromM3()
```